# Protecting Spring MVC against XSS

Tags: java, security, tomcat, spring-mvc, xss

I want to protect my app against XSS. Is there any out of the box feature I can use? An external library to secure requests on the whole application? Or a Tomcat filter/valve?

Thanks!

Comment: See [HDIV](http://www.hdiv.org/) this has support for multiple security risk and integration with Spring MVC.

Answer (score 1):

Options you can use:

1. [Java Encoder Project](https://code.google.com/p/owasp-java-encoder/) (just does encoding)
2. [HDIV](http://hdiv.org/) (Does a couple of security things, however it doesn't do them all as well as it should).
3. ESAPI (Does a lot of stuff, including encoding) - sorry, I can't post a second link, but you can google it. :-)

If all you want is encoding, I would go for option 1. It'll be the quickest and easiest.